# Why does S3 CORS allow methods that I have not specified in the CORS configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Why does S3 allow me to PUT objects to the bucket using a PUT HTTP request despite only specifying a GET in allowed method?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Why do you believe that your CORS configuration should prevent you from making a `PUT` request to the bucket?  Is the `PUT` request occurring in a cross-origin browser context?  You have not provided enough information to actually suggest that something isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>` CORSRule node simply indicates what value should be returned in the `Access-Control-Allowed-Methods` response header for a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. That will then be checked (in the browser) against the method which is about to be used for the real request.

It **does not** have anything to do with which methods are **actually** allowed for requests.

However, if your request is a 'simple' CORS request which doesn't need preflighting, then there's no checking in the browser - it just makes the request.

That being said, a PUT request shouldn't be a simple request, so can you post your **full** request/response headers here?